# Unhandled JS Exception : Unexpected identifier 'PropTypes'. import call expects exactly one argument when exporting flow types in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, flowtype

I am trying to update my React native project from 0.55.4 to 0.56.0 After running the app I am getting the following error

```
Unhandled JS Exception : Unexpected identifier 'PropTypes'. import call expects exactly one argument
```

When I dig down why I am getting that error I came to know that when I am using

`export type SomeType = {}`

this error popups.

I am assuming it might be because of wrong babel configuration. If I just keep

`type SomeType = {}`

only I am not getting any error

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-react-native", "@babel/preset-flow"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [["flow-react-proptypes", { "ignoreNodeModules": true }]]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

Versions in `package.json`

```
"@babel/cli": "7.0.0-beta.47",
"@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.5.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.47",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0-beta.47",
"@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0-beta.47",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
```

Comment: Are you using React [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)? Based on the error, it doesn't seem related to Flow as much as PropTypes. Also, can you post the line that has the `import` statement that is causing the exception?

Comment: ```import type { Profile } from './types' . Yes PropTypes are being used in my repo @user11307804

Comment: Are PropTypes being imported in the same file that contains `import type { Profile } from './types';`?

Comment: No @user11307804